# Collecting occurrences in a HashMap with streams

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, method-reference

I've got an exercise to solve. I've got a Fox class, which has got name and color fields. My exercise is to find the frequency of the foxes by color.

Thus I've created a HashMap, where the String attribute would be the fox name and the Integer would be the occurrence itself:

```
    Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
```

Having done that, I have been trying to write the code with streams, but I am struggling to do that. I wrote something like this:

```
    foxes.stream()
    .map(Fox::getColor)
    .forEach()
    //...(continued later on);
```

, where foxes is a List.

My problem is basically with the syntax. I'd like to do something that if the color has no occurrences then

```
    freq.put(Fox::getName, 1)
```

else

```
    freq.replace(Fox::getName, freq.get(Fox::getName) + 1)
```

How should I put it together?

Comment: IMHO, the latter part of the question is confusing the initial motive. Mixing up name and color there changes the complete question intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest proceeding with your approach simply because there is already a built in the collector for this i.e. [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector with [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) as downstream:

```
 Map<String, Long> result = foxes.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Fox::getName, Collectors.counting()));
```

This finds the frequency by "name", likewise, you can get the frequency by colour by changing the classification function.

```
foxes.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Fox::getColor, Collectors.counting()));
```